# BASE_DIR output within a subfolder, DJANGO

Tags: python, django

Ever since I changed my `settings.py` file to be in 3 different files (i.e. base, local and production) within a subfolder 'settings', `BASE_DIR` will not display the path to project correctly.

What I want BASE_DIR to output is the following:

```
`PathToProject/Projectname`
```

what I am getting (since I moved BASE_DIR in base.py within 'settings' subfolder:

`PathToProject/Projectname/Projectname`

It bothers me because now it's looking for `static` folder within `Projectname/Projectname` instead of `Projectname`

How could I properly configure BASE_DIR function to give me the correct path to project?

Comment: You went "up" one directory for your settings, where BASE_DIR is defined, so you'll need to go "down" one directory in the definition of BASE_DIR: `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))`  (that is, one extra `dirname`).

Comment: Yeah this fixed it :), may I just ask why did you use `os.path.abspath`? I did not use it and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Django (1.9 at least) itself starts a new project with BASE_DIR defined with `os.path.dirname` & `os.path.abspath`.

Comment: As for why and the difference: try yourself on the Python cmdline, with and without abspath.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## About having several custom settings.py files :

I suggest you to keep your default main `settings.py` and make custom ones aside if you need some.

If you need to derivate it, make other `settings.py` files for instance for your preproduction version. make your `preprod-settings.py` like this, in the same directory that `settings.py` :

```
from .settings import *

DEBUG = False # <-- just add some settings or override the previous ones like this.
```

This way all your main settings are in the main file, and you only need to put what you want to change in your custom settings files. You'll then be able to change what settings file to use with the `manage.py`'s `--settings` option, or by modifying (or make a custom one) `wsgi.py` file in production, with for instance :

```
import os, sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.mycustomsettingsfile")
SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, os.pardir))
sys.path.append(PROJECT_PATH)
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

## How BASE_DIR (should) works :

When creating your project, `BASE_DIR`'s default value is :

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

which means :

"BASE_DIR is the parent folder of the parent folder of the file this line is in (settings.py).".

`os.path.dirname()` gives the parent folder path, and `os.path.abspath()` the absolute path (you need it to give `os.path.dirname()` enough informations to get the parent dirnames).

Since `BASE_DIR`'s value is computed each time you run your server, and since this valus simply depends of the `settings.py` location, you don't need custom values for several locations or cases :

You move your project --> `BASE_DIR` automatically changes.

### "But what if I move my settings.py?"

If you move your settings.py file, you may have to change the `BASE_DIR` value : for instance, if you move it deeper, just add a `os.path.dirname` to your `BASE_DIR` assignation.

**NB :** if you want to choose what project to run amongst several subprojects (it seems weird to me though, I'm not sure I understood well. It could ever be wrong, feel free to describe what you want to achieve and why, maybe we could suggest a better way), you could still override the `BASE_DIR` value in your custom `settings.py` files.

Comment: A nice thorough anwser. Well I was googling for a good practice of separating settings.py in production and development, and i found a way which in my opinion gave a nice separation of the 2 [(click)](https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project/tree/develop/project_name) . However since this example is for Django 1.6 which did not have the function BASE_DIR I was unsure how to come around this problem. 
Looking at your anwser I might need to change my `manage.py` file a bit though (atm i have something simmilar to the linked example.

Comment: @narn I'm glad if it helped but `BASE_DIR` isn't a function : It's just a variable and its value is a string.

Comment: @vmonteco thank you. Nice answer and worked perfectly. I move my settings file into \web\web\ __settings\dev__ \settings.py, so my new value looked like this .......... "BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))))" ... in other word, I wrapped to old value with this    __os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(....)__