# Django BASE_DIR give different path in different views

Tags: python, django, view, path

views.py

```
def download(request, path):
    print(settings.BASE_DIR)
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, path)

    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/octet/stream")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404
    
def profile(request, username):
    print(settings.BASE_DIR)
    ....
```

Here in profile view `settings.BASE_DIR` is giving correct path (`D:\MiniProject\django-project\ProjectBlog`) which is set in the **settings.py** file, but in **download.py** its giving wrong path (`Profile/download/`).
Why is this duelity?

Comment: Check in your code maybe you're overriding your **BASE_DIR** value somewhere.

Comment: No I have checked it.

Comment: Hello @Vansh_Chaudhary this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36823429/base-dir-output-within-a-subfolder-django) will help you

Comment: Now i get it correctly, but BASE_DIR and path are not joining accordingly as they should be. file_path = (os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, path), this is giving me something like this - D:/images/Nitro_Wallpaper_5000x2813_Vm2jvWw.jpg. BASE_DIR is (D:\MiniProject\django-project\ProjectBlog) and path is (/images/Nitro_Wallpaper_5000x2813_Vm2jvWw.jpg) then file_path has to be (D:\MiniProject\django-project\ProjectBlog\images\Nitro_Wallpaper_5000x2813_Vm2jvWw.jpg). Please explain.